# CasperJS, mutliple element click during scrape

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to scrape a page, and return all the data as JSON. The process is that I first open www.domain.com, I pull various bits of info into the "nodes" array, but then for each node, there is another page I'd like to pull additional data from and store in the nodes array. I need to do this within the loop, or at least be able to pass the "x" variable around so I know where to push this data into the array.

I've stripped this code right back and haven't checked it works, but the main version I have works fine

Any help is greatly appreciated...Thank you

```
var nodes = {};

var casper = require('casper').create({

    pageSettings: {
        loadImages:  false,           
    },             
    verbose: true                   
});


var url = "http://www.domain.com";


function get_rows() 
{
  var nodes = {};

  var el = document.querySelectorAll(".rows");

  nodes["rows"] = {};

  for(var x = 0; x < el.length; ++x) 
  {
    // Set the arrays
    nodes["rows"][x] = {};


    nodes["rows"][x] = el[x].innerHTML;


    // THIS DATA IS ON A SEPARATE PAGE
    // el[x].click IS HOW YOU'D VISIT THAT PAGE
    nodes["rows"][x]["data"] = {};

  }

  return nodes;
}


function get_data()
{
  casper.echo("get_data");

  rows = casper.evaluate(get_rows);

  casper.echo(JSON.stringify(rows));

}

casper.start(url, function() 
{
  this.echo('Starting...' + this.getTitle());
});

casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0');
casper.viewport(320, 480);

casper.waitFor
(
  function check() 
  {
    return this.evaluate(function() 
    {
      return $('.content').is(':visible');
    });
  }, 
  function then() 
  {    
    this.capture("/work/screen.png");

    // Lets go get the data
    this.echo("About to get_data()");
    get_data();
  }, 
  function timeout() 
  { 
    // step to execute if check has failed
    this.echo("Timeout: page did not load in time...").exit();
  }
);


casper.run();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to split your `get_rows` function into multiple functions. The first one would retrieve the number of `.rows` elements. `casper.getElementsInfo()` provides an `html` property for every matching element and is callable outside of the page context.

```
var nodes;
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
casper.then(function(){
    nodes = {
        rows: {}
    };
    var elements = this.getElementsInfo(".rows");
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        nodes.rows[i] = {
            html: elements[i].html
        };
        (function(i){
            // TODO: click on the correct link
            casper.thenClick(x("(//*[contains(@class,'rows')])["+(i+1)+"]//a"));
            casper.then(function(){
                nodes.rows[i].data = this.evaluate(function(){
                    return { stuff: "whatever" }; // scrape here
                });
            });
            casper.back(); // assumes this works for your page
        })(i);
    }
}).then(function(){
    this.echo(JSON.stringify(nodes.rows, undefined, 4));
});
```

The IIFE (`(function(i){...})(i);`) is important otherwise only the last `i` would be populated. This happens because JavaScript has function level scope and CasperJS' `then*` functions are asynchronous.

If `casper.back()` doesn't work for you, you will need to load the main page anew with `casper.thenOpen()`.

Comment: I'm not sure that would work as the get_rows() function as this is called within an evaluate call in which CasperJS is out of scope?

Comment: That is why you have to split it into multiple steps and most of them have to be executed outside of the page context.

Comment: Thanks Artjom, I'll have a play around and see what gives

Comment: It hasn't really, not really any further forwards but I do appreciate your reply.

Comment: You're probably having trouble finding the correct link to click. I changed the my answer with a little helper. If you want to give up, ask a new specific question.

Comment: This article gives a better idea of what I am trying to achieve.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16160707/casperjs-how-to-click-multiple-links-in-a-table-while-collecting-data-from-the-w - however, I haven't got as far as figuring if the click is working or not...

Comment: I am trying to click the element using casper.thenClick("div.myClass:nth-child("+key+")");

Comment: `casper.capture()` the page in the `then` step following the click.

Comment: Yeah I've tried that to see if it's actually getting to that page, but it doesnt get into the "then" step.

Comment: Please register to the [`resource.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#resource-error), [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error), [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`casper.page.onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) events. Maybe there are errors.

Answer (score 0):

This is where I am at so far...the first evaluate returns an object and works perfectly fine, but within each "fixture" I want to go a get another page of data, the element to click on is just a repeated class called ".Fixture" so I'm using nth-child() to try and target the relevant element. The code never actually gets to create the capture

```
    fixtures = casper.evaluate(get_fixtures);

  casper.echo("Fixtures: "+Object.keys(fixtures).length );

  casper.then(function()
  {    
    Object.keys(fixtures).forEach(function(key) 
    {
      casper.echo(fixtures[key]["competition"]);

      (function(key)
      {
        casper.echo(".Fixture:nth-child("+key+")");

        var pageturnString = key.toString();
        var linknum = 'div.Fixture:nth-child('+pageturnString+')';

        casper.thenClick(linknum);

        casper.then(function()
        {
          casper.capture('/work/screen_click.png');
        });
        casper.back(); // assumes this works for your page
      })(key);

    });

  }).then(function()
  {
      casper.echo("END");
  });
```